# Watch and evaluate expression in attribute on a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

(I can't make the title any shorter because I'm really trying to do everything at once.)

What I want to do is this:

```
<mySlider max="25 * scopefunction(scopevar)" 
          step="scopevar=='foo'? 0.5 : 0.25"/>

<myOtherDirective factor="0.4/scopefunction(scopevar)"/>
```

Whenever the results from these expressions change, the directives need to update stuff. There's a radiobutton that switches `scopevar` between two values, and when that happens, both `mySlider` and `myOtherDirective` should change the way they work; the slider gets a different max and a different step, and the other directive gets a different factor that's used in some calculations.

At the moment, I'm relying on

```
scope.$watch(attrs.max, function(newVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
}
```

which works fine for `step` and `factor`, but for `max`, `newVal` mysteriously becomes `NaN`. And `scopefunction()` really always returns a number. So how can it be `NaN`? In what way is the `max` case different from the others?

My directives both have isolate scope. `scopefunction()` is a function on the parent scope, so it can't be called from inside the directive. And I wouldn't want that, because I want the directives to be as generic as possible, because they get reused a lot. And in most places they're not used with these calculations, so I want to keep the way these attributes are used as simple and clean as possible from the outside.

I've tried it with and without

```
scope: {
    max: '@',
    step: '@'
}
```

which didn't seem to matter much, because I'm already using `attr.max` directly.

I'm stumped. Why is `max` different? How could this possibly not work?

**Addition:** the problem seems to be that 'scopefunction(scopevar)' is evaluated to 'undefined', resulting in NaN when I multiply it. What I still don't understand is why it works gine in `factor` and `step`.

I made [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D1TdHwZahAhGgtKwaO89?p=preview) that shows max failing and step succeeding. Unfortunately I can't reproduce `factor` working anymore. At least not with isolate scope. When I remove the isolate scope, `factor` works. That would suggest I need to remove the isolate scope, but I'm not sure I want to do that. I don't want my directives polluting the parent scope.

Comment: I've added a plnkr, but I can't quite reproduce what I thought I had at some point: factor working with an isolate scope. It does work without an isolate scope, but I think I really want an isolate scope here.

Comment: I think I may have to drop the isolate scope. The problem with that is that I can't use `scope: {ngModel: '='}` to update a value on the scope. Is there another good way to do that?

Comment: Dropping isolate scope seems to mean I can't update ngModel from inside my directive. I really do need two-way binding for that, and that only seems to be possible with isolate scope. Instead I wonder if point 8 in https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750 might be the solution.

Comment: I don't want this calculation in the directive, because it's not the directive's concern. The directive is reused a lot, and I need this only in one of them. If I move it, I should move it to the controller. But my controller is also fairly generic, controlling the entire app op several views. I don't have a separate controller for every view, and this is logic that's only relevant to this view. Maybe I should move it to the controller, but then I need databinding between different fields in the data model. Angular handles model-view databinding automatically, but not model-model databinding.

Comment: I do have separation of concerns. I actually have two controllers for the entire app: one for navigation, one for data. But those don't change throughout the app. Most of the app is just very basic data binding and some directives. This one view is really the only view where I seem to need any additional logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way that seems to work, is fairly simple and preserves isolate scope. The `scope: { max: '&'}` turned out to be fairly useless. I still have no idea how to use that. The best way seems to be to put the logic in the controller, and use interpolation, one-way data-binding and $watchers to keep everything up to date.

Controller:

```
$scope.maxFunc = function() {
    return 25 * $scope.scopeFunction($scope.scopeVar);
}

$scope.stepFunc = function() {
    if ($scope.userInputData === 'maand') {
        return 0.5;
    }
    else {
        return 0.25;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div slider min="0" max="{{maxFunc()}}" step="{{stepFunc()}}" ng-model="sliderValue"></div>
```

$watchers in the directive's controller to ensure that the updated values are converted to numbers, because the `"{{maxFunc()}}"` will turn them into strings:

```
$scope.$watch('min', function(min) {
    $scope.min = $scope.parseInt(min, 1);
});
$scope.$watch('max', function(max) {
    $scope.max = $scope.parseInt(max, 10);
});
$scope.$watch('step', function(step) {
    $scope.step = $scope.parseFloat(step, 1);
});
```

That's pretty much it, I think. My other sliders that don't rely on a variable max still work as they always did.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the **$watch** to monitor any expression like this:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    // return x + y;
    // return myObject.myProperty;
    // etc.
    return myFunction();

}, function(newVal) {

    console.log(newVal);

}
```

More details about **$watch** on [AngularJS API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Interesting idea. The problem is that I can't evaluate the formula inside the directive, because the directive has isolate scope and doesn't have access to the parent scope. And I'd like to keep it that way. So the formula needs to be evaluated in another way.